# How to get option set values from sql server in an application outside crm

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

How to get option set value of an entity from sql server. I have developed a windows application , in which i was getting option set from crm using impersonization. But now my requirement is to get the value from sql server using sql server credentials but not with crm credentials.

Comment: Does this mean you want to get the value from a column on a record, or you are trying to get all the possible values of an option set?

Comment: Need all possible values of an optionset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select
    e.Name as EntityName,
    e.ObjectTypeCode,
    s.AttributeName,
    s.AttributeValue,
    s.Value,
    s.DisplayOrder
from
    StringMap s 
    inner join EntityLogicalView e on
        s.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode
where
    e.Name = 'new_entityname'
    and s.AttributeName = 'new_optionsetname'
```

Answer (score 3):

Direct SQL access is obviously unsupported but if you need to grab the info anyway, you need to look at the `StringMap` view. You can then filter by entity and attribute name as required.