# Executing muliple Stored Procedures within a single SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

My SQL Server Agent job seems to execute the 1st SP cmd but not the second. Does anybody know how i get multiple commands into a single Server Agent job?

[image: my agent job]

Comment: Can you not make it two steps or create a single stored proc that executes the two.

Comment: I can of course but its more of a curiosity as to if i can do this - i would prefer to do this from a code layout standpoint.

Comment: the first stored proc does execute without an error doesn't it?

Comment: iT Does indeed but perhaps there is some ending/closing statement that needs to be added?

Comment: TBH I think your command should work. Nothing being logged in job history? If you seperate them do they run sucessfully one after the other?

Comment: I have exactly the same working on my machine. There must be some sort of error preventing the second from executing

Answer (score 1):

Use the GO command after executing each stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you reference any FilteredViews in your sproc code? Then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955249/sql-server-agent-job-completes-but-stored-procedure-doesnt-run) post and see if you can implement any of these solutions.